# Insert BsonDocument into Collection in C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I try to use JSON string to insert into the Mongo Collection.
I follow up the instruction from [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.0/reference/driver/crud/writing/)
Here is my code

```
StringBuilder JsonString = new StringBuilder();

if (vdtSource.Rows.Count > 0)
{   
   JsonString.Append(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vdtSource, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented));  
}

// convert JSON to DBObject directly 
   BsonDocument document = new BsonDocument();
   document = BsonDocument.Parse(JsonString.ToString());  
   await MachineLogRawDataCollection.Insert(document);
```

and the problem occurs at `await MachineLogRawDataCollection.Insert(document);`

If you have any advice, could you give me some hints?

Thank you,
Thomas

---

Here is my full code to resolve my problem:

```
IMongoDatabase Database = objMongoClient.GetDatabase("MachineLog");
IMongoCollection<BsonDocument> MachineLogRawDataCollection;
MachineLogRawDataCollection = Database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("machinelograwdata"); 


if (vdtSource.Rows.Count > 0)
{
    BsonDocument document= new BsonDocument(); 
    foreach (DataRow dr in vdtSource.Rows)
    {
        document.Clear(); 
        intRowCount += 1; 
        foreach (DataColumn dc in vdtSource.Columns)
        { 
            document.Add(dc.ColumnName.ToString(), dr[dc.ColumnName].ToString()); 
        }
        MachineLogRawDataCollection.InsertOne(document); 
        document.Clear(); 
    }  
}
```

`

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Any exception stack trace, log or screenshot of error would help.

Comment: Hi, zendu. thank you for spending time with me.
yes, from VS, it shows error:
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'MongoDB.Bson.BsonDocument' to 'ReadRawDataWithMongoDB.MachineLogRawData'`

Comment: MongoCollection.Insert() seems to be sync method. You may want to remove `await` keyword. If you are sure that collection object is not from legacy driver and from newer async driver, then change the method to InsertOneAsync().

Comment: Well, there is your answer. The `MachineLogRawDataCollection` is of type `MongoCollection<ReadRawDataWithMongoDB.MachineLogRawData>`. You can insert only objects of type `ReadRawDataWithMongoDB.MachineLogRawData`. Instead of converting `vdtSource` to `BsonDocument`, translate it to `ReadRawDataWithMongoDB.MachineLogRawData` and then pass it to `Insert()` method.

Comment: Let me explain my scenario a little bit.
1. Read a file line by line and Insert into `DataTable` object.
2. From `DataTable` object , I convert to JSON string (I use Newtonsoft.Json to convert)
3. Create BSON Document from JSON string at step 2
4. Insert into Collection  from  BSON Document << I'm stuck in here

`ReadRawDataWithMongoDB.MachineLogRawData` is my internal class , it's only for definition Properties , there is no method on my class.

Comment: I believe `MachineLogRawData` is your POCO class that represents schema of document to be inserted in collection. If yes, you need to use appropriate library to convert line from file to the POCO object. If not, declare the collection as `MongoCollection<BsonDocument>` and not `MongoCollection<MachineLogRawData>`.

Comment: yes, `MachineLogRawData`  represents schema of document.
Thank you for your advice, zendu. Let me try and give feedback in this topic so it can help others.

Comment: Change step 3 to create a `MachineLogRawData` from json string using Newtonsoft.Json or create `MachineLogRawData` from `DataTable` object.

Comment: I have another way in my mind to resolve it.
From `DataTable` , I convert to JSON for each `Row`
my string is  ` "ColumnName_1":"ColumnVaue_1" , "ColumnName_2":"ColumnVaue_2" , .. ,"ColumnName_n":"ColumnVaue_n"   `

and I will insert into Collection for each Row data.

in this way, I won't convert to JSON string.

Comment: Hi Veeram and zendu, 
I use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(vdtSource, Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.Indented);` to convert as JSON string. Output looks like 
`[
  {
    "TimeStamp": "2017-04-17T05:56:26.000",
    "MachineID": "PKII_K011047",
    "EventID": "01" 
  },
  {
    "TimeStamp": "2017-04-17T05:56:26.265",
    "MachineID": "PKII_K011047",
    "EventID": "20" 
  }
]` . How can I insert into Collection from above text?

Comment: Dear all,
I resolved my problem already.
I try to post my complete code but the length is too big.
I will modify my question content instead.
Hope, it can help others.

Thanks to zendu and Veeram for your advices and suggestions.